# Varchar to nvarchar without changing length

Tags: sql-server, database, unicode, alter-table, nvarchar

I have this table that stores an id for each row in sub_id column of type varchar(255), sql server. Other columns store unicode thus those are nvarchar. Now I have this need to update sub_id to nvarchar for SOME reason. I ran following command:

```
 ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ALTER COLUMN SUB_ID NVARCHAR(255)
```

This changed the column type but set the length to 510. I do not want to change length of the column. If I must mention, table has a lot of data and length of sub_id never exceeds 20.

I read about this and could not figure out how to truncate the column in length.

Following is snapshot from sp_help on mentioned table (subject_id is sub_id)

[image]

Comment: What makes you think the length changed the 510?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=69f3752216979d40a0c382fb72e99556).

Comment: @Larnu sp_help  shows increased column length, attached snapshot

Comment: @Larnu , may be he is telling about `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH'

Comment: @pyroCoder , You can alter by specifying `NVARCHAR(127)` which will have a `DATALENGTH` of `254`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are looking at `sp_help`, length means the following ([sp_help (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)):

> Length    smallint    Physical length of the data type (**in bytes**).

It does not mean the length of the column in characters.

A single `nvarchar` character is 2 bytes in size, not one. The maximum length of the column hasn't changed, but its size in bytes has.

If you want the **Data size** of the column to remain the same, you would have to make the column an `nvarchar(127)`/`nvarchar(128)` (which would be 254/256 bytes in size), and would truncate your values.

Comment: I tried 'select from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ....' which gives me 255 only. Thanks. Limited understanding of sp_help lead to the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The size of `NVARCHAR` is `255` and it Occupies 2 bytes of space for each character, that's the reason it showing `DATALENGTH` as `510`

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(20)  
SET @string = 'Robin'  
SELECT @string AS 'String', DATALENGTH(@string) AS 'Datalength' , LEN(@string) AS 'Len'
```

[image]

As in the output above, you will observe `DATALENGTH` column is showing only 10 as a value. That is because it occupies 2 bytes of space for each character and the data length is only 5 characters, therefore it will occupy 10 bytes of space in the database.

Comment: Thanks , this was very useful.